# Pagination on AWS Apigateway DynamoDB proxy

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

If I want to have a resource on the API Gateway like

GET `/comments`

and there are hundreds of items at that route I would need to paginate those items. As far as I can see the API Gateway only provides a `next` parameter according to these [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/resources/).

So I could actually use these parameters to create a pagination, but as there is no information about the total number of items I could not create a "typical" pagination like

< 0, **1**, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... >

Or am I missing something here? How do Webapps consuming dynamodb over apigateway handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process of getting a total count from a distributed system is a costly process.

When you query, it just get the top available data on the first return giving you a marker. When you pass in the marker you will get the next available batch of data. By doing a scan for all the available data will be a costly process and slow down the page requests.

If you really need a total count of the records in a table, you can maintain an **atomic counter** in a record that gives you the total counts of the rows in another table.

**Atomic Counters:**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters

Hope it helps.